# How can I improve the robustness of reflection?

Tags: java, android

I'm modifying someone else's open source library to better suit my needs, and in the process I'm realizing that the library itself is rather fragile. It has no tests, and critical parts of its code use reflection to get around permissions levels in the Android SDK. I recognize this is bad practice, but I agree with the original author in this case that some parts of the SDK that are marked private or package private should be protected or public.

For example, one class does nothing but extend a standard Android UI class, but provides a getter and setter for the color of one of its views which cannot otherwise be changed.

Obviously, code that relies on private code in someone else's codebase in inherently brittle, but I figure the least I can do is write some tests for it. But the only thing I can think of is to instantiate it, change the color, and see if it crashes. Assuming there's no way to do what I want without accessing private members, what can I do to make this more palatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing much more comes to mind. I would add some unit tests that exercise the particular reflection code you want and see if it crashes / maintains correct behavior. You are relying on deliberately hiddne impl details of a 3-rd party library -- as you say that's text book definition for disaster at some point. So outside of coming up with a migration plan of removing this code ASAP, I would simply write unit tests covering all affected code (though in reality most of your app should be covered by unit tests already; and integration tests for what you cannot unit test)